# Hovering horizontal line displaying y values of multiple lines Matplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using df.plot to plot several lines in a simple 2D plot. I'm trying to create something like a hovering cursor that displays the y values, however, I would like for it to be a horizontal line that would then display all line y values at the same x location.

```
### BASIC plot from DF
plot = report_df.plot('timestamp', ['Tmax', 'Tmin','delta', 'SOC'])
# SHOW VALUES
mpc.cursor(hover=True, multiple=False)
plt.show()
```

I've tried the cursor widget as well as mplcursors, however these only display the y value for 1 line at the time. The mouse must hover each line. What I'm looking for is a horizontal line that will display all curve y values at the same time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please share your code showing your attempt.